# Create virtual interface for serial port?

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, debian, usb

I have a new version of a device that has a microUSB port, whereas the old device had a serial port. I have some python code that should, in theory, work for sending data to the new device, except for the fact that the code uses the pyserial library. Is there any quick hack I might be able to use, like emulating a serial port and routing data from that into the new device, or something, that might be able to allow me to use my old python software with this new device?
Thanks, and sorry for being so general.

Comment: That depends on the device and if it has a USB to serial chip.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to be more specific about what device you have and what its USB interface is like.  You can use the `-v` option of `lsusb` to print out all the descriptors of the USB interface.